# Bluetooth code is not working in Android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 lenovo tab

Tags: android

My Code

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{

 String pos = applist.get(arg0);
 File f = new File(path + pos);
 Uri path = Uri.fromFile(f);
 Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
 intent.setType("text/plain");
 intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
 startActivity(intent);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to do? Not sure because of file and position thing it is not clear for me.

In case you just want to open Bluetooth settings this piece of code should do that for you:

```
Intent intentOpenBluetoothSettings = new Intent();
intentOpenBluetoothSettings.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS); 
startActivity(intentOpenBluetoothSettings);
```

that should be enought ;)

Hope that I helped. Enjoy